# jQuery detect/remove empty select and input DOM manipulation

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I've currently two inputs having the same names (I know it's a bit weird).
The first is a selectbox and the second is a text field.

What I want to do is to check if one is fulfiled and the other empty, then remove the empty one before submitting my form.

Here's my HTML :

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/helps" class="formtastic help" id="new_help" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">

<li class="select input required" id="help_category_input">

  <label class=" label" for="help_category">
    Category<abbr title="required">*</abbr>
  </label>
  <select id="help_category" name="help[category]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="First Category">First Category</option></select>
    <option value="Second category">Second Category</option></select>

</li>

<li class="string input required stringish" id="help_category_input">
  <label class=" label" for="help_category">
    Category<abbr title="required">*</abbr>
  </label>
  <input class="input2line" id="help_category" maxlength="255" name="help[category]" type="text" />

</li>

<li class="action button_action " id="help_submit_action">

  <button name="button" type="submit">Create Help</button>

</li>
</form>
```

I tried with the Jquery `submit` method and `empty` method, but I think I don't really know how to select properly the right field.

Can you help me do that please ?
Cordially Rob

EDIT: i've got something like that

```
if($('#help_category > option').empty && $('#help_category[type=text]').!empty{
  to_remove = $('#help_category > option')
  to_remove.remove
}

if($('#help_category > option').!empty && $('#help_category[type=text]').empty{
  to_remove = $('#help_category[type=text]')
  to_remove.remove
}
```

Comment: Do you have some Javascript / jQuery code that you have used to try this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#new_help").submit(function() {
    $("input[name='help[category]'], select[name='help[category]']", this).each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === '' || $(this).val() === null) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set both elements with the same id field (`id="help_category"`) this is not valid HTML.  Id attribute has to be unique.

Change the input id values, and use jquery's id selector to identify them.

```
<select id="help_category_select" name="help[category]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="First Category">First Category</option>
    <option value="Second category">Second Category</option>
</select>

<input class="input2line" id="help_category_input" maxlength="255" name="help[category]" type="text" />

$("#new_help").submit(function()
{
     var sel = $('#help_category_select');
     var inp = $('#help_category_input');
     if ((sel.val() === '' || sel.val() === null) &&
         (inp.val() === '' || sel.val() === null)
     {
         // Neither value selected - Prevent submission
         return false;
     } else if (sel.val() === '' || sel.val() === null)
     {
         sel.remove();
     } else {
         inp.remove();
     }
});
```